# Cannot pull webpage into an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to pull a webpage into an iframe on another webpage but it just keeps giving me a blank box. Any idea why this is not working?

My page: (https://www.skmgroupwork.com/facebook/identifix/fix/)

iframe code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.identifix.com/FOTW/FixFrame.aspx" width="700" height="600" scrolling="no" id="inneriframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: … because the page you are trying to display inside the iframe doesn’t _want_ this, and tells your browser not to do so via an `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`www.identifix.com` blocks external domains using their site in an iframe.

You can see here that they have set `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` which blocks all external domains iframing their site.

[image: www.identifix.com response headers]

Read more about [X-Frame-Options header here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).

Comment: How do I see the response headers on the site? Just view source?

Comment: @TerriSwiatek In Chrome hit `f12` to open `dev` tools, select the network tab, then refresh to log all requests and click whatever request you wish to see the headers off.

Comment: Thanks @KyleNeedham for all this I had no idea why and this resolved the issue for them.

Answer (score -2):

maybe the problem is in the domain of the webpage you want load, proib with other page for exclude problems, some domains of webpage block of call for iframes !!